# How to build application in both Android and ios

Tags: java, android, ios

How to build Application on both Andriod  and ios like in appmethod(its environment) but its not support for java platform is there any suggestion for java platform

Comment: Using phone gap you can develop for both -> Android, iOS.

Comment: Intel has recently introduced Multi-OS Engine: https://software.intel.com/en-us/multi-os-engine to create cross-platform iOS and Android apps using Java, it's free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With various tools you can develop cross platform app, such as

- Tool #1: Sencha
- Tool #2: PhoneGap
- Tool #3: Appcelerator Titanium
- Tool #4: Xamarin
- Tool #5: Qt
- Tool #6: Ionic